# Javascript ++ -- assistance

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the output of this script 5 instead of 8 ?

I thought `--` meant `-1` twice.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var x = 0;

      var y = 10;

      while ( x < y ){

        x++;

        y-- ;

      }

      document.write(y);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you think ++ did?

Answer (score 1):

First iteration:

```
x = 0
y = 10
```

Second Iteration:

```
x = 1
y = 9
```

Third Iteration:

```
x = 2
y = 8
```

When will `x` not be smaller than `y`? When `x` is equal or bigger than `y`:

```
x = 5
y = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To help you understand better the "`++` `--`" notation: `x--` is equivalent of `x=x-1` and so on.

Comment: Actually it issn't. `x--` returns x before it's decremented, this is important when used in an assignment or maybe a function call. While `x=x-1` returns `x-1`. So there's a subtle but rather important distinction.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, but I wasn't using x-- for an assignment example, I didn't say `x=x--` is equivalent to `x=x-1`

Comment: I know, but a novice programmer might not immediately see the subtilities.

Answer (score 0):

`--y` means decrement by `y` by 1, so on each loop `y` decreases by 1.

i.e. `y = y - 1`

The opposite is happing for `++x`. This means on each loop increment `x` by 1.

i.e. `x = x + 1`

The loop keeps going until `x` and `y` are the same, 5, hence the `while` loop condition is no longer satisfied, hence breaking the loop.

There is more details on incrementation and decrementation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_())

Answer (score 0):

The `++` operator increments a numerical value by `1` whereas the `--` operator does the opposite, decrementing a numerical value by `1`.

Here is what happens in your loop :

```
#Iteration    0       1       2       3       4       5
x value       0       1       2       3       4       5
y value      10       9       8       7       6       5
x < y      true    true    true    true    true   false  <-- breaking here (iteration 5)
```

From this tab you can see your loop ends at iteration `5` with a value of `5` for `x` & `y`.

Let's see what incrementing and decrementing `0` a thousand times does.

```js
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i+=1) {
  j++;
}

document.write(j);

document.write('<hr>');

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i+=1) {
  j--;
}

document.write(j);
```

Oviously `0` ends up being `1000` and `0` again.